# Extracted *.zip files downloaded using cURL, from GitLab, are automatically added a .git extension on MAC OS

Tags: php, macos, curl, gitlab

I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.

I have GitLab server on which I have a few repositories. I'm using their API, specifically Get file archive using cURL and PHP. Code bellow:

```
$file = fopen('archive.zip','w+');

$ch = curl_init();
//connect and login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/api/v3/projects");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("PRIVATE-TOKEN: private-token-goes-here"));

//get file archive
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/api/v3/projects/64/repository/archive");

//auto write to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); 

curl_exec($ch);
```

The file downloads properly and is saved on the disk.

However, when I try to unzip it MAC OS automatically adds a .git extension.

If I manually remove the .git extension it will be properly recognized as a folder and everything seems to be in order(no missing files, no corrupted files, etc).

This is a nuisance to say the least. I'm not particularly sure if my code is wrong, or there's something wrong with GitLab's API, or there's something wrong how MAC OS treats .git extension. To be perfectly honest I don't even know where to begin debugging. Google and/or SO doesn't have anything of significance either.

I'm using OS X Version 10.8.4

I'll leave a comment with their API link in the comments, because apparently I can't use links since I'm a new user.

Comment: [Link to GitLab API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/repositories.md#get-file-archive).

Comment: Maybe it is not OS X that adds the extension? Maybe archive already contains folder with such extension. Only some git handling app changed the way the folders with .git extension are displayed in `Finder`.

Comment: @baf You were half right. I uninstalled Tower, the default application for .git files and it recognized it as a folder. However, the .git extension is still applied to the folder. So `repo.zip` still extracts to `repo.git`, but now it does show up as a folder.

Comment: Are you sure that `repo.zip` doesn't contain `repo.git` folder? Try to run in terminal command  `unzip -t repo.zip`.

Comment: @baf Yes, I'm sure, [here's everything that the repo contains](http://i.imgur.com/qH5thp8.png).

Comment: How do you unzip the archive? Could you post the output of `unzip -t repo.zip` command? The command will test and list archive contents.

Comment: `End-of-central-directory signature not found.` So long story short, it can't find the line that signals the end of the archive. I assume I'm not downloading it properly and/or not setting the header properly.

Comment: What does `file repo.zip` say? Maybe that's not a zip archive?